# Kotlin convert DateTime to 10 digit TimeStamp

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to find out how I can convert DateTime to 10 digit timestamp in Kotlin (Android Studio), I can't find any equivalent of it in Kotlin.
For example:
I have a val with date-time value like :
`val dateTime = "2020-12-13 17:54:00"`
Now I want to convert it to 10 digit timestamp like "1607842496"
Please give me a simple sample to show how I can resolve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `SimpleDateFormat` class to parse your date `String` to a `Date` object. You can then get the timestamp (in milliseconds) from that `Date` object like so:

```kotlin
val dateTime = "2020-12-13 17:54:00"

val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault())
val date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateTime)
val timestamp = date?.time
```

Divide the timestamp by a 1000 to get the 10 digit (in seconds) timestamp.